# Filter between 2 numbers

Tags: netsuite

I have a custom record with 3 fields:
Minimum
Maximum
Rate

I would like to build a search that use a number in custom body field and if that number falls between the min and max number it will alert with the rate.

Can I do this via saved search or a scripted search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filters: [
  ["thenumberfield", search.Operator.GREATER_THAN, theMinNumber], "AND",
  ["thenumberfield", search.Operator.LESS_THAN, theMaxNumber]
]
```

Comment: Hi @erictgrubaugh -- this is actually backwards The min and max are the record fields and thenumberfield is the value from the current record.

Answer (score 1):

```
function compare(context){
var minnumber = nlapiGetFieldValue('minnumber');
var maxnumber = nlapiGetFieldValue('maxnumber');
var comparenumber = nlapiGetFieldValue('comparenumber');
var rate = nlapiGetFieldValue('rate');
if(comparenumber > minnumber && comparenumber < maxnumber){
  alert(rate);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a Client Script for this:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(["N/search"], function(search){


    function fieldChanged(ctx){
        if(ctx.fieldId == 'custbody_rate_definer'){ // use the id of your custom body field
            var definer = ctx.currentRecord.getValue({fieldId:ctx.fieldId});
            var rate = null;
            // use the actual values from your rate lookup custom record for the search
            search.create({
                type:'customrecord_custom_rates',
                filters:[
                    ['custrecord_max_val', 'greaterthan', definer], 'AND', 
                    ['custrecord_min_val', 'lessthan', definer], 'AND', 
                ],
                columns:[
                    'custrecord_rate'
                ]
            }).run().each(function(result){
                //this assumes your rates don't overlap and nothing else needs to be done to disambiguate the rate records (e.g. valid during some set of dates)
                rate = parseFloat(result.getValue({name:'custrecord_rate'})) || 0;
                return false;
            });

            if(rate) alert('The rate is '+ rate);

        }
    }


    return {
        fieldChanged:fieldChanged;
    }


});
```